# How to remove space from image name and replace with % in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to remove the space between image name and replace it with % . How can I achieve that?

Image path = 'http://combined/nature image GREY_120_240_Glossy_OBL Premium.jpg'.

I want it to be = 'http://combined/nature%20image%20GREY_120_240_Glossy_OBL%20Premium.jpg'

Code I have tried

```
$url = 'http://combined/nature image GREY_120_240_Glossy_OBL Premium.jpg';
            $decodeUrl = urlencode ($url);

            $name = basename($url);
            $upload = file_put_contents("uploads/$name",file_get_contents($url));
            if($upload){
                echo "okk";

            }
```

Comment: `urlencode()` resp. `urldecode()`

Comment: Encoded url parts as filenames might still make problems, depending on filesystem and software. The best is to replace them with scores, underscores, dots or another character. Just removing white space combined perhaps with conversion to camel case writing is possible too.

Comment: The problem here is, that `$url` is encoded, but `basename()` is called on the _original_ `$url`and not `$decodedUrl` (which is a funny name, because it actually contains the _encoded_ url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use rawurlencode and do it after pulling the name, presuming you want it on the naming.

```
$url = 'http://combined/nature image GREY_120_240_Glossy_OBL Premium.jpg';
$decodeUrl = urlencode($url);
$name = basename($url);
echo rawurlencode($name);
```

https://3v4l.org/CptPc

I would replace any whitespace with underscores.

```
$url = 'http://combined/nature image GREY_120_240_Glossy_OBL Premium.jpg';
$name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', basename($url));
```